# issue with json data (expected eof file but found {)

Tags: json

I am using json data but following is my json data.

```
{
   "data0":"data0",
   "data00":"data00",
   "data1":"data1",
   "data2":"plugin_prius_2012",
   "data3":"data3",
   "data4":"data4",
   "data5":"data5",

}{
   "data10":"data10",
   "data11":"data11",
   "data11":"data11",
   "data13":"data13",
   "data14":"data14",
   "data15":"data15",
   "data16":"data16",
   "data17":"data17"
}{
   "data10":"data10",
   "data11":"data11",
   "data11":"data11",
   "data13":"data13",
   "data14":"data14",
   "data15":"data15",
   "data16":"data16",
   "data17":"data17"
}{
   "data10":"data10",
   "data11":"data11",
   "data11":"data11",
   "data13":"data13",
   "data14":"data14",
   "data15":"data15",
   "data16":"data16",
   "data17":"data17"
}{
   "data20":"data20",
   "data21":"data21",
   "data22":"data23",
   "data":"data23"
}{
   "data20":"data20",
   "data21":"data21",
   "data22":"data23",
   "data":"data23"
}{
   "data20":"data20",
   "data21":"data21",
   "data22":"data23",
   "data":"data23"
}{
   "data20":"data20",
   "data21":"data21",
   "data22":"data23",
   "data":"data23"
}{
   "data20":"data20",
   "data21":"data21",
   "data22":"data23",
   "data":"data23"
}
```

What is issue with this json data? error says that expected eof file but found {

Comment: user2864740 i have tried validating these data on jsonlint.com and error says Parse error on line 8:
...ta5": "data5",    }{    "data10": "da
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's *not* JSON, but some text with parts that look like JSON. See http://json.org and http://jsonlint.com/.

Generally code should use a proper JSON library, which would not produce such invalid "JSON", and *not build JSON manually*.

I suspect that the *goal* (with data omitted for brevity) was an array, like:

```
[{"data0":"data0"}, {"data0":"data0"}, {"data0":"data0"}]
```

But see above: *use a proper JSON library*.

Comment: Good call on the missing "[]" needed to store multiple objects for standard JSON syntax.